# android up navigation bar always creates new activities

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this architecture:

`Activity 1` -> `Activity 2`

`Activity 2` has a navigation bar with the up navigation button. When I press it, `Activity 1` is created from scratch although the back button just goes back to `Activity 1`.

What should I do in order to make the `navigation up` not create `Activity 1` from scratch?

Comment: What do you do when up is clicked, call finish()? Remember that the runtime may kill Activity1 whilst 2 is showing if it needs the resources or there is a config change such as orientation. You can't prevent that so you should cater for the case where 1 gets recreated regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have this in `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: In activity1 or activity2 please? i am sure in activity 2, right?

Answer (score 2):

Actually I think you are creating a new Intent and navigating it instead of doing that you need to call `finish()` then check.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```